# How to override the universal selector *?

Tags: html, css

so I am trying to set all the margins and the paddings for the upper part to 0 then add padding and margin to the elements individually whenever I need to that's why I would like to override the color and the margin set by the universal selector * but it doesn't work, everything is staying deeppink and also the margin doesn't change, please help.

```css
/*------------------------All Margin & Padding-------------------------*/

.upperPart {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: darksalmon;
}

.upperPart * {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: deeppink;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

/*-----------------------------------Colors-------------------------*/

header {
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  background-color: mediumspringgreen;
}

nav {
  background-color: teal;
}

ul {
  background-color: magenta;
}

li {
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 5px;
}

li {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 2px;
}

div {
  background-color: brown;
}

section {
  background-color: lightsteelblue;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<!----------------------------THE UPPPER PART------------------------------------------->
<div class="upperPart">
  <!---------------------------HEADER-------------------------------------->
  <header>
    <h1>Untitled</h1>
    <img src="" alt="logo" name="logo" />
    <h3>description in form of a slogan</h3>
  </header>
  <!---------------------------NAVIGATION----------------------------------->
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Shops and Products</li>
      <li>Find Work/Worker</li>
      <li>New Shops</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!---------------------------SEARCH--------------------------------------->
  <div>
    <form method="post" action="searchAppPhp.php">
      <label>Search </label>
      <input type="text" id="search" size="50" />
      <input type="submit" name="search"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<!----------------------------THE MIDDLE PART------------------------------------------->
<div class="middlePart">
  <section>
    <article>

    </article>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="downPart">
  <footer>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: `</input>` is invalid. Inputs are part of the *Void Elements* and do not need a closing tag.

Comment: oh yeah, the IDE created it automatically, didn't pay attention to it. Thanks !

Comment: @FZs if we're talking about the same... you're suggesting to use `<br></br>` `<input></input>`. But before you do so read about Void Elements https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/syntax.html#:~:text=A%20void%20element%20is%20an,param%20%2C%20source%20%2C%20track%20%2C%20wbr. I'd also be glad to read your authoritative resource about the subject.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I might have expressed myself badly, but I didn't want to *suggest* to use closing tags, just stated that they are valid. I thought this based on what I've learned about HTML, and I misinterpreted the MDN docs page of `<input>` that confirmed me. However, I see now that you're right, later in the specification that you've linked, I clearly states that "*void elements **must not** have end tags*". So, thank you for informing me on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***CSS [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)***.

Since you used `.upperPart *`  to *null* styles instead of arguably-preferably using `* {}`.
And since we are not supposed to ever use `!important` (unless we really, really know what we're doing)...

you'll need to use a **more specific Rule** as override. I.e:

```
.upperPart header {
  background-color: darkolivegreen;
}
```

Etc. for all your *nulled* `.upperPart` descendant Elements (`*`).

### Suggestion:

Don't style TAGS directly (or keep it minimal, margins, font-size, paddings etc).
**Style only Classes or IDs**.

```css
/* QuickReset */
* {
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
}

/* DEFAULT STYLES FOR TAGS */

h1,
h2,
h3 {
  /* Keep it minimal */
}

nav {
  /* Keep it minimal */
}

ul {
  /* Keep it minimal */
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

li {
  /* Keep it minimal */
}

/* STYLES FOR SPECIFIC CLASSES */

.upperPart {
  background-color: darksalmon;
}

/* ...Etc... */
```

```html
<div class="upperPart">
  <header>
    <h1>Untitled</h1>
    <img src="" alt="logo" name="logo" />
    <h3>description in form of a slogan</h3>
  </header>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>Shops and Products</li>
      <li>Find Work/Worker</li>
      <li>New Shops</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <form method="post" action="searchAppPhp.php">
      <label>Search </label>
      <input type="text" id="search" size="50" />
      <input type="submit" name="search">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="middlePart">
  <section>
    <article>
      <p>ARTICLE HERE</p>
    </article>
  </section>
</div>
<div class="downPart">
  <footer>
    <p>FOOTER HERE</p>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: oh yeah, good idea, but still for knowledge sake, why doesn't it override the universal selector ? isn't it supposed to be the the last rule has more priority than the first rule. Thank you.

Comment: @Ermiv read more carefully: *"Etc. for all your nulled `.upperPart` descendant Elements (`*`)."* I would help more with a simpler solution - but I really don't know what are you doing with all those background colors.

Comment: yes, sorry, didn't notice it, but it isn't practical, can't I just set the universal selector then override it ?

Comment: Use just `* {margin:0; box-sizing: border-box;}` as your ***Quick Reset***. (I usually like the default Paddings so no need to use `padding: 0;` but you can add that one too).

Comment: Yeah, I did try that at the beginning and it works, I just wanted to do a universal selector under an element to change all its children only and not all the elements of the webpage but it doesn't seem to work. Thank you. Like `p h3 {}` which changes only the h3 under p.

Comment: @Ermiv  `H3` is not meant to live inside `P`. That's invalid HTML.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to coding. I meant something like `<div class="firstContainer"> <div class="secondContainer"></div></div>` which in CSS is like this: `.firstContainer .secondContainer {}`, so if I apply a change inside the curly brackets it will change only secondContainer not all what's under firstContainer, I want to apply the same idea with .upperPart * {}

Comment: @Ermiv as I said in my answer. Don't overstyle default TAGs. Use classes to apply specific styles to elements (like colors, shadows etc etc).

Comment: Ah okay, I see, thank you for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Ermiv - What you want isn't available ... yet. Soon, you will be able to write `:where(.upperPart) *` which will have zero specificity  and therefore be overridden by all following selectors. But right now, that's only enabled by default in Firefox. It'll be coming to Chrome soon.

Comment: @Alohci Thank you, that's the answer I was looking for, I didn't know whether it's available ot it's me who is doing something wrong, it seemed logically available, didn't seem like something hard to implement, but apparently it's not, Thank you.